# @typescript-eslint/no-shadow complains about shadowing variable that is just being declared

Tags: typescript, eslint, typescript-eslint

`@typescript-eslint/no-shadow` complains about shadowing a variable that is just being declared, while I think it should only bicker about variables that have already been declared:

1. I set `'@typescript-eslint/no-shadow': 'error'` in my eslint config.
2. I add the code `const person = persons.find((person) => person.id === 123);`

It produces the error `'person' is already declared in the upper scope`.

I think, I basically understand *why* that is: In javascript, `person` *is* in fact already declared inside the arrow function (in typescript it's type simply being `any`).

But I can't think of a use case in which accessing it from the inner scope is *ever* useful - is there one?

If not, shouldn't there be another eslint rule to prevent just *that* and an option for `no-shadow` to disable checking the variable that is being declared in the current statement?

Answer (score 1):

Answering your question directly: this is exactly what the [`ignoreOnInitialization` option](https://eslint.org/docs/latest/rules/no-shadow#ignoreoninitialization) does.

The [typescript-eslint rule](https://typescript-eslint.io/rules/no-shadow) is an extension on the ESLint rule. Per the typescript-eslint docs, it takes in all the options that the base ESLint rule does.

Generally speaking: if you're wondering whether an ESLint rule has a particular option, it's good to try reading the docs first. Each option in the rules -both in typescript-eslint and ESLint- are fully documented. You can try them in their projects' online playgrounds. [This is a link to try the provided code snippet in the ESLint playground with `ignoreOnInitialization`](https://eslint.org/play/#eyJ0ZXh0IjoiLyplc2xpbnQgbm8tc2hhZG93OiBbXCJlcnJvclwiLCB7IFwiaWdub3JlT25Jbml0aWFsaXphdGlvblwiOiB0cnVlIH1dKi9cblxuY29uc3QgcGVyc29ucyA9IFtdO1xuY29uc3QgcGVyc29uID0gcGVyc29ucy5maW5kKHBlcnNvbiA9PiB0cnVlKTsiLCJvcHRpb25zIjp7ImVudiI6e30sInJ1bGVzIjp7fSwicGFyc2VyT3B0aW9ucyI6eyJlY21hRmVhdHVyZXMiOnt9LCJlY21hVmVyc2lvbiI6ImxhdGVzdCIsInNvdXJjZVR5cGUiOiJtb2R1bGUifX19).

Comment: Whoops sorry - I missed that one  Thanks for your quick answer!